# How do I use importfeed in Google Sheets so that the most recent entry appears as the last row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out the formula for displaying the entries of an RSS feed in a Google sheet so that the most recent entry appears as the last row.

However, the way importfeed works, it shows the most recent entry as the top row instead.

```
=importfeed("https://waitbutwhy.com/feed","items",TRUE)
```

I have tried using the query function to sort by the date column, however the date column is not properly recognized/formatted resulting in a random order.

```
=query(importfeed("https://waitbutwhy.com/feed","items",TRUE), "select * order by Col4 asc", 1)
```

It seems like there are 2 possible solutions to this problem, either:

1. Reverse the order (using the row numbers?)
2. Properly format the dates and sort by that column

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`=query({query(importfeed("https://waitbutwhy.com/feed","items",TRUE),"",1),query(arrayformula(value(regexreplace(importfeed("https://waitbutwhy.com/feed","items",TRUE),"\ \+0000",""))),"select Col4 ",1)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 order by Col6,Col1",1)`

Two queries within an array `{}` separated by `,` so that the second query can select Col 4 and convert it into a date/time using `value` for a future sort. The regex removes  `+0000` before the `value` is applied.

Then a query wrapped around them to do the overall selection of columns `Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5` and sort by date ascending then Title. You don't need to add `asc` after the `order by Col6` since it's the default. You only need `desc` if you want to change the sort order to descending.